# Quarkus UnsatisfiedResolutionException for Mapstruct

Tags: dependency-injection, quarkus, mapstruct

I am trying to use Mapstruct in my Quarkus project, but when i run the app with `/.mvnw compile quarkus:dev` 
i got the following exception:

*javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type
org.acme.dto.mapper.BookMapper and qualifiers [@Default]*

(I have checked the generated classes in `target/generated-sources`, and they get `@ApplicationScoped`)

**Details:**

Mapstruct dependencies are added to the pom.xml as:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Than i have several mappers like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", uses = { BookDetailsMapper.class, AuthorMapper.class })
public interface BookMapper {

    BookDto toDto(Book book);
    Book toEntity(BookDto bookDto);
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public interface AuthorMapper {

    AuthorDto toDto(Author author);
    Author toEntity(AuthorDto author);
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public interface BookDetailsMapper {

    BookDetailsDto toDto(BookDetails bookDetails);
    BookDetails toEntity(BookDetailsDto bookDetailsDto);
}
```

And the BookMapper bean is injected in:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BookService {

    private final BookMapper bookMapper;

    @Inject
    public BookService(BookMapper bookMapper) {
        this.bookMapper = bookMapper;

}
    
...
```

Comment: is generated classes compiled and added to classpath?

Comment: im not sure about this, but in target/classes only the mapper interfaces are added, but not the implementations

Comment: in my project (eclipse) I have `target/generate-sources/annotation` directory added as classpath; maybe something related to maven and annotation processing; also I have `*Impl` under `target/classes/`

Comment: LMK if you resolve

Answer (score 1):

For last **jakarta** packages you need annotate you mapper interface with:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "jakarta")
public interface SomeMapper {
    ...
}
```

in my case I use lombok too:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
          <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.version.lombok}</version>
          </path>
          <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.version.lombok-mapstruct-binding}</version>
          </path>
          <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.version.mapstruct}</version>
          </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

And for usage:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {

   private final SomeMapper someMapper;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that generated-sources of mapstruct was not compiled to class files.

I had to add the `mapstruct-processor` dependency as follows:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>

            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>

            <path>
              <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
              <artifactId>quarkus-extension-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```